# Doze mode and GCM notifications

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, android-6.0-marshmallow

I've followed this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533972/how-to-shift-device-in-doze-mode-android-preview-m-marshmallow) to set my Nexus 5 device to the 'IDLE' state with adb, after switching off the screen.

```
> adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
> adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step
Stepped to: IDLE
```

Despite this, I am able to see through my device logs the GCM notifications being received.

`1-04 15:21:40.708 22138 26007 I GCM     : GCM message com.sample.app 0:1446610899548646%82d6ec5bf9fd7ecd`

My understanding is that Doze mode will allow for certain maintenance windows where normal priority notifications are pushed in a batch, so I was not expecting to see such log entry. (I have also logged all the entries in the received `Bundle` and can see all the attributes of the notification)

When I step the device into the `IDLE_MAINTENANCE` mode, I do not see the device receiving any further notifications (presumably since it has already received it)

I have been pushing notifications with payloads including and excluding the priority property, and it does not seem to make a difference.

I am testing on a device with Android Build Number MRA58K, with a project using Google Play Services version of 8.1.0.

In addition, I am not able to access the network (in response to a GCM notification) only when the device is in the 'IDLE' state, which suggests that the deviceidle step does have some effect.

Is there a step that I am missing in order to set the device into a proper 'IDLE' mode?

Comment: I just answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999016/android-doze-mode-gcm-priority/34078213#34078213).  I suggest you try Play Services 8.3.0.

Comment: Thanks @qbix, I've revisited the issue and upgrading to Play Services 8.3.0 (using Android 6.0.1) seems to have fixed the issue

Comment: Not sure if this constitutes as an answer, so I will post it as a comment instead. Reported the issue to google https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192856 and they have replied the issue has been fixed and will be available in a future build