# How to call Rxjava fucntion daily on specific time in Android?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I want to do the alarm type task using rxjava. I'm already using rxjava interval operator but this asks for time interval I don't want to give time interval instead I want to repeat the function daily on 12:00 am.

This is my code for interval-based Rx Observable:

```
return Observable.interval(delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS).timeInterval()
                .flatMap((Function<Timed<Long>, ObservableSource<CustomTime.TimeTempBuilder>>) longTimed -> getDataManager().getTimeByDate(date));
```

**Purpose:** I have a foreground service running daily I have to show the notification at a specific time.

Comment: what if your app is not running at 12:00 am?

Comment: i have a foreground service running don't need to worry about this.

Comment: Your foreground service might be dead.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce it is foreground service it will not dead.

Comment: I don't think you can make that assumption in a reliable manner, but ok

Comment: we have everything in working our foreground service working perfectly everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better not use rx for this. Instead take a look at JobScheduler or WorkManager. In case of use rxjava, your action won't be fired if main thread will be finished by system or user. But WorkManager API provides to you ability to configure a lot of options, including time, which indicated when system should start your job.

Comment: dear, I already have mentioned in the question that I'm using foreground service which is running 24/7 without any interruption. going with Rx looks better in my case.

Comment: `which is running 24/7 without any interruption.` what is the guarantee of this? You might need `evernote/android-job` or using AlarmManager manually.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce there is no need in evernote/android-job, because of WorkManager is a standalone library

Comment: @NoumanCh checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048010/how-to-test-doze-mode-on-android