# Android - Disable Forced DozeMode or AppStandByMode

Tags: android, android-doze, battery-saver, android-doze-and-standby, android-appstandby

I have an application that uses a `ForegroundService` to send location updates to a server. Basically a tracker.

This `ForegroundService` has a `Handler` that periodically (using **postDelayed**) executes a block of code to send the location.

This works perfectly fine, when the app is in the foreground and even in the background, but I started to notice a *delay* when the phone is locked, with the screen off for about 15minutes. I mean, 15 minutes of no user activity and no charger plugged.

This is happening on a **Android Q (v10)** device. I'm assuming this would also happen on any device running Oreo onwards.

Let's make it clear... My app send the location every 30sec, but when entering what I suppose is the **DozeMode** or **AppStandByMode**, it continues sending the location, but every 2 minutes (more or less). If I turn the screen on, or plug-in the charger it inmediately come back to the 30sec pace. That's what makes me thing about the **DozeMode** or **AppStandByMode**. Moreover, if I leave the phone untouched, but with the charger plugged in, then this never happens.

As said, I'm pretty sure the **DozeMode** or **AppStandByMode** is kicking in, and I know I can whitelist my app to prevent that. But before going further I would like to reproduce this without the need to wait those 15minutes every time I want to test the behavior of my app.

So I "googled" how I can force this and here's what I've found:

For `DozeMode` (see [source](https://medium.com/@mohitgupta92/testing-your-app-on-doze-mode-4ee30ad6a3b0))

> adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
>
> adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step deep

And continue to execute the last command until reaching **IDLE** state.

For `AppStandByeMode` (see [source](https://medium.com/google-developers/testing-app-standby-b8b90c4f411))

> adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
>
> adb shell am set-inactive *packageName* true

And query the state with this other command:

> adb shell am get-inactive *packageName*

which I confirm it returns **Idle=true**

I also even do as [this other blog](https://wolkowicz-mateusz.medium.com/simple-android-doze-mode-testing-365acf127ab4) suggest, issuing:

> adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle

I though I was not getting in this mode, but now it seems I am and I can not get out of it... See the update

#### UPDATE

At first I thought I was not entering the DozeMode... Now I can confirm I'm in, but it always triggers inmediately. (no more waiting those 15min)

Whenever I lock the phone and screen goes off, it automatically enters the doze mode and begin spacing the location updates. I plug the charger and then again sends them at 30sec.

I've try:

> adb shell dumpsys deviceidle unforce
>
> adb shell dumpsys deviceidle disable
>
> adb shell dumpsys battery reset

and still the same.

Also:

- power-down and power back up the phone
- uninstall the app
- change battery optimization to NOT OPTIMZE inside the app settings

Did I miss a step?

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel, I don't understand how that could be a solution

Answer (score 0):

Except for Doze mode, Android 9 extended the concept of AppStandby with [App Standby Buckets](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/appstandby).

Along with network restrictions, an app that is in a low priority bucket will be affected in the frequency of running Jobs, triggering Alarms, and receiving FCM messages.

You can get your app's current bucket using this command:
adb shell am get-standby-bucket your.package.name

You can set the bucket and see how your app behaves using this command:
adb shell am set-standby-bucket your.package.name <never/rare>

I wrote an article that summarizes all changes regarding background process limitations over the years: https://rotemmatityahu.medium.com/workmanager-does-it-always-manage-to-work-fd8518655052

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll try that